# List Workflows page throwing error

Tags: 2013, workflow

I am on SP 2013 and when I navigate to a List Item and click on ... and ... and click on workflows it throws and an error something went wrong and throws a correlation ID and its on the Dev Enviornment and other environments are working fine as expected.

I have checked the Publishing feature, Workflow Task Content Type, Workflow can use app permission is activated.

Note - This is the Root Site in the Dev Environment

I did check the ULS Logs and found this and many more but other didn't make sense

Application error when access /_layouts/15/Workflow.aspx, Error=The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
 at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
 at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.HttpGetResponseAsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult result)
 at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)

I was browsing through the CA and found the Upgrade Status has failed not sure if its related.

I tried running the PSCONFIG.EXE -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b and it fails on step 4 and bring down the CA
I have to run Product COnfig Wizard and it runs successfully and CA is back again but the upgrade status still says fails.[image]

Comment: You have to check the ULS for that specific correlation id, from where you will get teh clue.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE I update the questions with some more info, hope that helps

Comment: Is it a 2013 workflow or 2010? What is the authentication scheme on your web application?

Comment: did you configured the workflow manager properly?

Comment: @Nisarg there is no workflow manager in my environement its all OOB and Designer workflows and we have Claims Authentication(NTLM)

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE we don't have Workflow Manager configured everthing is OOB and Designer

Comment: is it 2010 or 2013 workflow?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE right now there are no workflows but we moslt use 2010, does it matter if its 2010 or 2013 just curious because I cant even get to the workflow page the page itself is broken

Comment: @SavantProdigy Had something similar happen to a SP2013 environment. It was due to an update not being installed, workflows ran fine but the workflow  management page didn't work. Can't remember what update it was though

Comment: @Roland just realized that my Dev env is on SP1 15.0.4569.1000 ​Service Pack 1(​KB2880558) and my Prod/QA is on  15.0.4745.1000 August CU, working on fixing that not sure if it is related but I trying to eliminate errors

Comment: @SavantProdigy Found the patch that I installed that fixed it for me: See here for everything: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b189e4b8-bb9e-4ade-a3d5-cd2e0f90e93f/workflow-not-working-after-installing-service-pack-1-and-patches

Comment: @Roland Instead of doing the ones recommended by you I installed the August CU which will cover all the HotFixes and previous CU and I had to try 3 times to get the August CU installed and multiple attempts to run Product Config Wizard and it still didn't fix the problem. I found out that the after the patch install that patch somehow removed access of this service account to the DB WFInstanceManagementDB and WFResourceManagementDB.Informed DBA to run a script to fix that issue and its all good now - Issue Resolved - Thanks everyone for jumping in